# Can't update AWS App Runner after creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-app-runner

The app runner is successfully created and works fine, but any attempt to change the configuration gets an error. It seems that the healthcheck does not work, although after creation everything works fine.

```
[AppRunner] Service status is set to RUNNING.
[AppRunner] Service update failed. For details, see service logs.
[AppRunner] Performing health check on path '/healthz' and port '8080'.
[AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image.
[AppRunner] Service status is set to OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS.
[AppRunner] Service update started.
[AppRunner] Service status is set to RUNNING.
[AppRunner] Service creation completed successfully.
[AppRunner] Successfully routed incoming traffic to application.
[AppRunner] Health check is successful. Routing traffic to application.
[AppRunner] Performing health check on path '/healthz' and port '8080'.
[AppRunner] Provisioning instances and deploying image.
[AppRunner] Successfully pulled image from ECR.
[AppRunner] Service status is set to OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS.
[AppRunner] Service creation started.
```

This happens with any change. For example, here I just changed the healthcheck interval from the default 10 seconds to the maximum 20.

At the same time, it is impossible to find any logs explaining what went wrong. Cloudwatch just duplicates the message `Service update failed. For details, see service logs`.

If it matters, I'm running the application inside a VPC, with NAT configured. There is also a private db instance with access only from the VPC. Healthcheck `/healthz` checks access to the internet and to the database, there are no problems with this.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or where I can find useful logs would be helpful.